# Curl not found (Glype)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to install proxy software called Glype on my server. It continues to tell me that "Glype requires cURL/libcurl". I have the latest version of curl installed. Why might this be happening? Glype runs with PHP, and the curl binary is in /usr/bin and is `rwxrwxrwx`.

Comment: I know nothing about Glype, but maybe it requires libcurl? How exactly did you try to install Glype (what did you download, what commands did you run, etc.)? **Do not make files rwxrwxrwx**, it is never the answer. Don't change the permissions of a file if you don't understand *why*.

Comment: a link to a pastebin of the error might be nice :)

Comment: @Gilles It said it requires curl or libcurl. It's a bunch of php files in a folder, and you are supposed to run one for settings.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded glype and found it's a PHP program, so what you need is not libcurl or CURL binary, but php_curl module,

`apt-get install php5-curl` should work for you.

If you're running php with apache, simply restart apache will finish the installation:

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: That should be `php5-curl` with a '-', not a '_'. Simply installing the package will enable the module, since php5 in debian uses a split configuration system. Apache will need to be restarted if mod_php is used though.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to look at the application and find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more info, such:

- What distro are you using? (or *nix flavor)
- Version of Glype

My recomendation is that you should install `libcurl`

E.g. in a Debian machine:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep curl
ii  curl                                 7.21.0-2.1+squeeze2                  Get a file from an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP server
ii  libcurl3                             7.21.0-2.1+squeeze2                  Multi-protocol file transfer library (OpenSSL)
```

Check if you have the library already installed with the command of `dpkg` stated above or since you are you're using Linux Mint, you should be able to install `libcurl` by issuing:

```
apt-get install libcurl3
```

Or you can use any other package available.

Comment: I'm using linux mint 13, newest glype (on the network I need glype for, so can't go to page to find the version). Libcurl is worth a try, but if either is supposed to work, I don't see why the lib would work and not the executable.

Comment: @lucase.62 I've edited my response, let us know if that solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your query and the tests you have done, it seems you have cURL installed in the first place and it looks pretty much like php is not able to find the curl path even though it is installed properly. troubleshoot it further by putting a `phpinfo` page in the doc root and see if php is taking the curl that is installed. if it does then you may need to check if curl is working as it should be. do a sample script that runs curl function and see if it gives any errors.